# Adding additional info to someone else's question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so thanks in advance for helping both a newcomer to the site and a very inexperienced coder.

I am having this same problem as:

[jScrollPane cropping vertical content Chrome / Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745331/jscrollpane-cropping-vertical-content-chrome-webkit)

but the behavior I'm experiencing is slightly different than described in the question and I don't know enough to know why. Should I respond to the existing question with something to the effect of, "I'm having the same problem but in Android my code does this and in Safari it does this," or is there some better way to go about it?

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for trying to figure out the best way to handle this! This situation can unfortunately be a bit awkward on SO, but ChrisF's answer should cover you.

Answer (score 15):

Create your own question.

Link to the question you've found, but make it clear that the behaviour you are seeing is different. This *should* stop it being closed as a duplicate.

Editing the question you've found won't really help as the existing answers refer to the original form of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions of how to edit a post, which are now not anymore visible to who has the privilege of editing a post, as the inline editing is used for such users, are:

- fix grammatical or spelling errors
- clarify meaning without changing it
- correct minor mistakes
- add related resources or links
- always respect the original author

Altering a question to make it what you want to ask is not a reason to edit an existing question.
You should ask your own question, if it is different enough to be considered a totally different question, and not a duplicate of the already asked one.