# What can you do if you find out that your question really is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

The problem: After searching SO for quite a while, you don't find an answer to your question. So you put some effort and research in asking a [*good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

After posting, someone points out that your question was already answered somewhere else. You check the question and the answer and realize that they solve your problem as well.

So, you obviously have created a duplicate! People are starting to vote it down...

What should I do after reading [Handling Duplicate Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/)?

- Delete
- Flag
- Any other possibility?

Note: An alternate title to the question could be "What should you do when your exact question has already been asked and answered properly?" as opposed to
*[What should you do when your exact question has already been asked, but badly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138198/what-should-you-do-when-your-exact-question-has-already-been-asked-but-badly)*.

---

After reading the comments I undeleted my [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822559/android-how-to-install-emulator-vor-api-level-11-13-android-3).

Comment: Duplicates are useful sign posts to the main question.  Assuming you agree and have the privilege: join in the voting as duplicate (there's no reason to flag as duplicate though since the initial vote will put it in the close queue)

Comment: Duplicates shouldn't usually be voted down, unless they are really really lazy. They need to be closed, but they're officially welcome to stick around.

Comment: If pointed question is differ with your question then you can indicate it in comment else check the solution. If the solution is not as per your requirement then make again comments. if solution is fit then delete your question.

Comment: [flag / vote to close it as a dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "for the reasons explained here, see '1. You discover that one of the answers in duplicate solves your issue'")

Comment: If you couldn't find the dupe with the search terms you used, and you created the question using those terms then it's likely that other people would / will also use those terms when searching for a question. Therefore it should exist as a duplicate and point to the main canonical post to help everyone when they're searching for the item. So in answer: vote to close as a dupe. Ignore downvotes; if it's downvotes for being a duplicate then that's no reason to downvote.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. As I result, I undeleted my question and flagged it as dupe. I hope I got you right. Another one in the close queue ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822559/android-how-to-install-emulator-vor-api-level-11-13-android-3

Comment: Oh, the irony!  possible duplicate of [What should you do when your exact question has already been asked, but badly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138198/what-should-you-do-when-your-exact-question-has-already-been-asked-but-badly)

Comment: Not this time! Plz see my edit.

Comment: Ironically, your SO question got [Roomba'd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314070/343832) :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We now have [a new UI for questions with a duplicate vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes). If someone flags your questions as a dupe, you get a box telling you the question that yours might be a dupe of and a button that says, "That solved my problem!". When you hit this button, your question automatically closes.

Comment: And if you somehow find the duplicate yourself before anyone else, you can currently flag your own question and then confirm it to close.

Answer (score 4):

> "What should you do when your exact question has already been asked
>   and answered properly?"

Vote/Flag to close your question as a duplicate of the other question.

I wouldn't recommend deleting your question since deleting your question is said to cause more harm then having a question closed as a duplicate. Thus deleting your question can hurt against you more by increasing your chances of being question banned.